# Stop background from refreshing?

Tags: processing

I am trying to get my gif to do something similar to [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGVP3.gif).

I have been able to get the line to draw, and the 'planets' to orbit, but can't figure out how to keep the line connecting the two circles, like the gif does.

Here's the basic code:

```
int x = 500;
int y = 500;
int radius = y/2;
int cX = x/2;
int cY = y/2;

String text1;

int lg_xBall;
int lg_yBall;
int sm_xBall;
int sm_yBall;

void setup() {
  size(x, y); 
  smooth();
  colorMode(RGB);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);

  float t = millis()/1000.0f;

  drawSmBallOrbit(100);
  drawLgBallOrbit(100);
  moveSmBall(t);
  moveLgBall(t);
  sun();

//  showMouse();
  connectingLines();

}

void drawCircle() { // This will draw a simple circle
  stroke(1);
  // x1=a+r*cos t, y1=b+r*sin t
  ellipse(x/2, y/2, x/2, y/2);
}

void drawLines() {  // This will draw lines from the center of the circle.
  stroke(1);
  line(x/2, y/2, radius/2, radius); // line from 6 to center
  line(x/2, y/2, x/2, y/4); // line from 12 to center
  for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i+=2.5) {
    float x1 = x/2+radius/2*cos(i);
    float y1 = y/2+radius/2*sin(i);
    line(x/2, y/2, x1, y1);
  }
}

void moveSmBall(float ky) { // This will create, and move, a small 'planet'
  pushStyle();
  stroke(100);
  sm_xBall = (int)(cX+radius*cos(ky));
  sm_yBall = (int)(cY+radius*sin(ky));
  fill(190, 0, 0);
//  background(0);
  ellipse(sm_xBall, sm_yBall, 10, 10);
  popStyle();
}
void drawSmBallOrbit(float opacity) {
  pushStyle();
  stroke(255, opacity);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();
  ellipse(x/2, y/2, cX+radius, cY+radius);
  popStyle();
}

void moveLgBall(float kx) {
  kx = kx/.7;
  pushStyle();
  lg_xBall = (int)(cX+radius*cos(kx)*.6);
  lg_yBall = (int)(cY+radius*sin(kx)*.6);
  fill(0, 0, 230);
  ellipse(lg_xBall, lg_yBall, 30, 30);
  popStyle();
}

void drawLgBallOrbit(float opacity) {
  pushStyle();
  stroke(255, opacity);
  strokeWeight(1);
  noFill();
  ellipse(x/2, y/2, (cX+radius)*.6, (cY+radius)*.6);
  popStyle();
}

void sun() {
  pushStyle();
  fill(250, 250, 0);
  ellipse(cX, cY, 40, 40);
  popStyle();
}

void connectingLines() {
  line(sm_xBall, sm_yBall, lg_xBall, lg_yBall);
}

void showMouse() {
  text("X: " + mouseX, x/2, y/2-30);
  text("Y: " + mouseY, x/2, y/2-50); 
}
```

Thanks for any help/advice!

Comment: What do you get now - only the one single line that connects your planets? Then you have to save each new x/y pair into an array, and draw that as well.

Comment: @Jongware - exactly, I only get the single line connecting planets.  Hmm, that's a good idea. Any tips on where/how to implement this? Would I need to create a global array, pass the values from the moveLgBall/moveSmBall subs to that array, then in the "connectingLines", create lines with the array? I am having trouble visualizing how to do this over the loop.

Comment: I don't know enough of Processing to suggest the correct syntax. I guess you could give your idea a go and see how far you can get.

Comment: @Jongware - I'll give it a shot.  Will have to work out how to pass the variables into the array, and draw a line and NOT have that line be "erased" when the background refreshes... hmm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `background()` during every frame, which will clear away anything you've already drawn.

So you either need to stop calling `background()`, or you need to redraw the old lines every frame.

If you simply move the call to `background()` out of your `draw()` function and into your `setup()` function, you're about 50% there already:

```
void setup() {
  size(x, y); 
  smooth();
  colorMode(RGB);
  background(0);
}

void draw() {
 // background(0);
  stroke(255);

  float t = millis()/1000.0f;

  drawSmBallOrbit(100);
  drawLgBallOrbit(100);
  moveSmBall(t);
  moveLgBall(t);
  sun();

//  showMouse();
  connectingLines();
}
```

[image: example animation]

However, the original animation does not show the previous positions of the ellipses. So you need to clear away the previous frame by calling the `background()` function, and then redraw previous line positions. You'd do that by having an ArrayList that holds those previous positions.

Here's a simple example that uses an ArrayList to redraw anywhere the mouse has been:

```
ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500); 
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  stroke(255);

  points.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));

  for(PVector p : points){
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 10, 10);
  }

}
```

You would need to do something very similar, but you'd have to keep track of two points at a time instead of one, since you're tracking two ellipses and not just the mouse position.

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for my delayed response. I'll look in to this and let you know what I am able to do/not do.